# Radar Tracking Algorithms

Tags: radar, tracking

I would like to know the algorithms to get the angle, range, distance.. so I'm planning to do antenna tracking. What should I do in basic steps to track objects using that module ?

what algorithms are used in automobile radar ?

Comment: some auto radars are monopulse. the company that makes the module should have sales and support engineers that support using their products. This isnt a customer support web site.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz I'm not looking for support, I'm looking on what are the algorithms that are used to use that module ?

Comment: Actually you are asking for support. If you asked “what algorithms are used in automobile radar” it would be valid. When you bring a specific product into your question, it is a customer support issue.  Ask them.  They want to sell their parts. They designed it a certain way for a reason.

Comment: what algorithms are used in automobile radar

Comment: edit your question

Comment: Can I please ask you to clarify your question a little bit? I find it difficult to understand what is being tracked and what is being "steered" if you like. Where does "automobile" come into play? Are you inside one vehicle and you want to track where another vehicle is to steer an antenna towards it? Do you use RF throughout? Is there optical tracking involved as well? Is it a specific automobile radar application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one system that I know of that is used on large trucks is mono pulse.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopulse_radar

The segment is very cost sensitive, so you’re not going to see much that wasn’t invented at least 50 years ago but given that Deep Learning is being thrown at every problem under the sun....

I would think that Continuous  Wave would have some use.

My understanding is that multiple sensors of type and purpose are used, so elaborating on the specific application would generate more specific responses.

As an example, the RADAR I looked at, was to help in lane changes. It didn’t need much in the way of range. A system for braking would have other characteristics.